# Normalizing weekly sales fluctuations in the overall market

Tags: correlation, normalization, seasonality

I have a rudimentary question regarding how to "normalize" a set of time series data, and would appreciate your thoughts.

To make it very simple, the hypothetical situation is as follows: 
Suppose we have the products A and B, both of which are of similar nature and functions and can be used as a substitute each other. We have weekly sales data of each product. 
There are 10 competing products out in the market, which are similar to our products A and B, and the overall weekly market data for those 10 competing products are also available.

We want to know to what extent our products A and B tend to cannibalize each other, and would like to know the correlation between the two, based on their weekly sales data. However, the overall sales volume in the market (for our 2 products and the 10 competing products combined) tend to fluctuate from one week to another, and the fluctuations require us to adjust or normalize them before calculating the correlations between products A and B. Suppose that the weekly market fluctuations are indexed as follows:

```
Market: 
Wk1  100 (=base)
Wk2  109 
Wk3  103
Wk4  101
Wk5   96
Wk6  108
Wk7  117
Wk8  147
Wk9  135
Wk10 115
```

Then for the purpose of normalizing or adjusting weekly sales volume of the product A and B so that they would supposedly show sales numbers with overall market fluctuations being adjusted, we would calculate the adjusted weekly sales by this index. For instance, suppose the WK2 raw sales data for product A is 36, and then the adjusted WK2 sales for Product A is 33, which comes from 36 divided by 109 times 100.

Does this make sense? or do we have better or more adequate ways to deal with the situations?
Thank you for reading this for the rudimentary question and I would appreciate your thoughts. 
I would very much appreciate your thoughts.